# Why aren't these two ways of making an async call (one uses a promise, the other a generator) producing the same results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a small node script that fetches users from Github using node-fetch (window.fetch compatible API on Node.js runtime). I then console.log the users, as can be seen below, using the returned Promise from fetch:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import "babel-polyfill";

const fetchUsers = lastReceivedId =>
  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users?since=${lastReceivedId}`);

console.log("Promise-based:");
fetchUsers(0)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The above works perfectly.

I now want to do the same thing using a generator together with the promise:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import "babel-polyfill";

const fetchUsers = lastReceivedId =>
  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users?since=${lastReceivedId}`);

function* main() {
  try {
    const res = yield fetchUsers(0);
    console.log("Response in generator is ", res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

console.log("Generator-Promise-based:")
const it = main();
const p = it.next().value;
p.then(
  function(response) {
    console.log("initial response is ", response.json())
    it.next(response.json())
  },
  err => it.throw(err)
);
```

This version does not work. The output is:

```
Generator-Promise-based:
initial response is  Promise {}
Response in generator is  Promise {}
```

**Why aren't these two code snippets producing the same result?**

Note: this is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "NodePractice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "generators.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src --watch -d lib"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "node-fetch": "^1.6.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) you must not call `response.json()` twice 2) instead of doing `it.next(response.json())` you still need to wait for the promise: `response.json().then(x => it.next(x))`

Comment: In any case, don't try to use generators with promises yourself except for experiments. Just go for `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older Node version is likely used in the example. Current Node versions (6 and higher) have promise implementation that handles unhandled rejections by default, this provides feedback on error handling and eases debugging a lot (that's the reason why unhandled rejection handling was introduced).

Then the output would look like

> initial response is  Promise {  }
>
> Response in generator is  Promise {  }
>
> (node:12364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: body used already for: https://api.github.com/users?since=0

And this indicates the problem. Calling `response.json()` twice results in error, and `response.json()` returns a promise (errors from which weren't caught).

Instead it should be

```
const it = main();
const p = it.next().value;
p
.then(response => {
    const jsonPromise = response.json();
    console.log("json promise is ", jsonPromise);
    return jsonPromise;
})
.then(json => {
    console.log("initial response is ", json);
    it.next(json);
})
.catch(err => { 
   console.error('error', err);
   it.throw(err)
})
```

It should be noticed that it is a good exercise to study generators, but for practical use [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) is widely known for implementing this approach.

Comment: The problem is calling response.json() twice? So if I keep my original code and remove the line console.log("initial response is ", response.json()) then it should work right? But it doesn't. Your solution does work perfectly though.

Comment: No, the problem is both that you call response.json() twice and expect it to be json object, while it is a *promise* of json object.

Comment: I upgraded my node version to v.7.10.0. And am using the change above, which only calls response.json() once, saves it to a variable r and then calls it.next(r). Now the output is slightly different, in an illuminating way, but still doesn't work: Generator-Promise-based:
Response in generator is  Promise { <pending> }

Comment: I get it, so response.json() returns a promise, which is still pending when I call it.next(r). If, in the first then, I return this promise instead, and use it in the next then call, it only gets used when it is fulfilled.

Comment: That's correct. I guess the version that is idiomatic to generator/promise pattern is `const res = yield fetchUsers(0); const json = yield res.json(); ...`.